# Background file upload MVC 5

Tags: c#, jquery, asynchronous, background-process

I am uploading large files to server about 4-5 GB. I have currently used HTML 5 and javascript `var reader = new FileReader();` to upload the file payload chunk by chunk to the action method and it will write to the file.

Problem with current uploading is if the user navigate to another tab in application or accidentally close the browser, file upload will stop because it's getting chunk using javascript on page. My requirement is also just upload and forget some background task will upload it for you.

I need some background thread that handle the file upload and upload the file in background. Like file upload queue. So if the user navigate to other page the file upload won't stop and continue in background.

Is this possible with web application? I did my research and found that thread is not a good idea on IIS, instead windows service should be used. But don't know how to do this.

I am not a pro so any idea/example will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: i afraid this is not possible in web application, because whenever user navigate to any other page, last page will be destroyed and thus all background worker will be destroyed too.